# A nonempty open set that contains all rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

Give an example or argue that an example is impossible. A nonempty open set that contains all rational numbers.

This was a question on my undergrad Real Analysis exam. There is a similar question that has been asked on the site but I don't understand the answer given. We have not discussed topology at length. I want to say that it is impossible since I think $\mathbb{Q}$ is neither open nor closed. But I'm not sure how to explain this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: How about $\mathbb{R}$? It's open and contains all rationals. Did you mean strictly open?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the concept of strictly open. If the set is not strictly open does that mean it's neither open nor closed?

Comment: The phrasing here is quite ambiguous: "A nonempty open set that contains all rational numbers" could either mean an open set $U$ such that $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq U$ or an open set $U$ such that $U\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$.  I'm guessing the latter is the intended meaning since otherwise the question is rather silly...

Comment: @Lanous Strictly open means open but not closed.

Comment: I think I'm going to take advantage of the poor word choice and use $\mathbb{R}$ as my example. I gave an answer close to the one given by Jean at the bottom and received $1/3$. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hard to talk about open sets without some conception of topology, so I'll try to give a crash course. A set is open iff there is an open ball around every element in the set. An open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x_0$ is the set of all $x$ st $\lvert x_0 - x \rvert < r$. In particular, all the open balls in $\mathbb R$ are the open intervals. For instance, the open interval (a, b) is an open ball centered around $\frac{a + b}{2}$ with radius $\frac{b-a}{2}$.

Now to answer your question, we are trying to find an open set- a set such that every point in the set is enclosed by an open interval- that contains all the rational numbers. That's why some of the answers are suggesting the real number line, which itself is open. Or, as pre-kidney suggested, take $\mathbb R$ and remove a point in $\mathbb Q$\ $\mathbb R$, like $\mathbb R$ \ $\sqrt2$. Then every point on $\mathbb R$ has an open interval around it except for $\sqrt{2}$, which isn't in the set anyways, so the set is open and contains all the rational numbers.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb R$

For an example that is open but not closed: $\mathbb R\setminus \{\sqrt{2}\}$

Comment: Or take your favourite Cantor $C$ set in the irrationals, and take $\mathbb{R} \setminus C$.

Comment: Right, one can enumerate the rationals and take an open interval around each rational. I suppose you would consider the complement of such a set to be a "generalized Cantor set"?

Comment: Not always. But there are lots of subsets homeomorphic to the Cantor set inside the irrationals. The open interval around any rational constrruction creates open sets of arbitrarily small measure though.

Comment: So by a generalized Cantor set, do you mean a homeomorphic image of the ternary Cantor set?

Comment: Yes, this is standard usage. A space homeomorphic to the ternary Cantor set is called "a Cantor set"

Answer (score 1):

If you want strict subset then take the union of intervals $(\sqrt{2}+n-1,\sqrt{2}+n)$ for every integer $n$. Note that only points missing are the points of the form $\sqrt{2}+n$ are irrationals since $n$ is integer. So the union contains all the rational numbers and being a union of open sets is open.

Comment: I believe the question is asking for an open set strictly containing only the rationals, although it is worded poorly.

Comment: Maybe this is why I was confused. I believed that he meant only the rationals. There is a chance that the word choice of "all" was intentional.

Comment: This makes more sense since $\mathbb{R}$ minus any irrationnal point satisfies the definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an open subset containing only irrationnal numbers, it doesn't exist. Since it has to be opened, then for any $x$ it contains, it also contains a neighbourhood of $x$. This neighbourhood can be taken without loss of generality as $U=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$. Now, since both the rationnals and the irrationnals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, then by definition there is at least a rationnal number in $U$.